# Flutter - Cubit & Navigation 2.0: emitting new page from page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, bloc, flutter-navigation

I am trying to create a website with Flutter using Navigation 2.0 and BLoC pattern. To do so, I read the following guides:

- https://medium.com/@JalalOkbi/flutter-navigator-2-0-with-bloc-the-ultimate-guide-6672b115adf
- https://lucasdelsol01.medium.com/flutter-navigator-2-0-for-mobile-dev-bloc-state-management-integration-3a180b4d25b3
- and this repo: https://lucasdelsol01.medium.com/flutter-navigator-2-0-for-mobile-dev-bloc-state-management-integration-3a180b4d25b3 (which implements the first guide).

**However I am facing an issue where I am trying to push a new page from one of my website displayed page: the new page is never displayed!**

**To understand:**

1. Each pages are pushed via a `MainNavigationCubit`. This cubit's state (meaning pages) is maintained within the `NavigationStack`.
2. My `MainNavigationCubit` is responsible for building the `Navigator` in my custom `RouterDelegate` (see code below). So upon a **state change** it rebuilds the `Navigator` with the proper list of pages.

**The problem context:**

- I have a "Book" page which displays the details about a specific book.
- In order to get the details, it expects a `book id`.
- If the book id is invalid or not found, then the "404 not found page" is pushed via `MainNavigationCubit`.

This can happen, eg, if the user is manually inputting a correct URL to the book page but with an invalid ID.

**However the "404 not found page" is never displayed although the `MainNavigationCubit` properly emits a new `NavigationStack` with relevant pages.**

---

This is the code from my custom `RouterDelegate`:

```
@override
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> get navigatorKey => GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'main_navigation_key');

@override
Future<void> setNewRoutePath(PageConfig configuration) {
  if (configuration.route != homeRoute) {
    mainNavigationCubit.push(configuration.route, configuration.args);
  } else {
    mainNavigationCubit.clearToHome();
  }
  return SynchronousFuture(null);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocBuilder<MainNavigationCubit, NavigationStack>(
    builder: (context, stack) {
      return Navigator(
        pages: stack.pages,
        key: navigatorKey,
        onPopPage: (route, result) => _onPopPage.call(route, result),
      );
    },
  );

@override
PageConfig get currentConfiguration => mainNavigationCubit.state.last;
bool _onPopPage(Route<dynamic> route, dynamic result) {
  final didPop = route.didPop(result);
  if (!didPop) {
    return false;
  }
  if (mainNavigationCubit.canPop()) {
    mainNavigationCubit.pop();
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And this is the code from my "Book" StatelessWidget page:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (bookId == -1) {
    context.read<MainNavigationCubit>().showNotFound(); // let's assume this will be properly handled when I'll be creating this page's BLoC.
  }
  return // full book details UI;
}
```

And just in case the code of `MainNavigationCubit.showNotFound()`:

```
void showNotFound() {
  clearAndPush(notFound);
}

void clearAndPush(String path, [Map<String, dynamic>? args]) {
  final PageConfig pageConfig = PageConfig(location: path, args: args);
  emit(state.clearAndPush(pageConfig));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after a lot of investigation I have found the reason for my issue.

As the documentation says: **a Cubit won't notify listeners upon emitting a new state that is equal to the current state.**

In my case, my `MainNavigationCubit`'s state is a `NavigationStack` which I took from this guide: https://medium.com/@JalalOkbi/flutter-navigator-2-0-with-bloc-the-ultimate-guide-6672b115adf

Looking at the code, the `NavigationStack` exposes methods that mutates an internal list of pages.

**The problem is this list belongs to the current state**, therefore modifying it means to also modify the current state.

As both current and new state rely on the same exact list, the Cubit won't emit the new state.